# React native + Android + text alignment issue

Tags: react-native, alignment, textinput, text-alignment, text-align

I have a React Native app that uses.

- react : 16.0.0-alpha.6
- react-native : 0.44.2

And in it I'm using `TextInput`

**The problem is on Android, if the text is more than the TextInput can handle, it's getting right aligned instead of left**

[image]

I'm expecting it to show something along the lines of :
**Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur...**

This works fine on ios. This issue is only happening on android.

`<TextInput
    style={inputStyle}
/>`

`inputStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    flex: 0.6,
    textAlign: 'left,
    borderWidth: 1,
},`

I made few attempts and the best solution I have so far is to enable `multiline` on TextInput. But **I don't want to have a multiline text input. I want a single line TextInput with left text alignment.**

*This is how it looks like with multiline*

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Had this issue myself. One alternative is to use the TextInput's selection property, e.g.

```
selection={{start: 0, end: 0}}
```

Just make sure you remove the property on input focus (in case the user wants to edit the text again).

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

`inputStyle: {
    fontSize: 20,
    flex: 0.6,
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    textAlign: 'left,
    borderWidth: 1,
},`

flexWrap takes the property of autoHeight adjustment and increases the height of the component based on the content inside it.

Src: [Layout Props](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#flexwrap)

Comment: Sorry, but that does not work for me. I also don't want to have a 'multiline' text input. I want a single line text input and the text in that to be left aligned. Like on ios.